# How to make a variable reactive in loaded content in Vue JS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue JS 2 component that displays translations.

`<translation :phrase="language.initial_delay_help"></translation>`

The data is loaded in to the app in a xhr repsonse and some translations may contain a tag.

`vm.language = r.data.language;`

An example translation string with a tag:

`The first notification will be shown after {{ popupSettings.initial_delay }} seconds`

The translations loaded in the response are binded but the tags are not compiled.

How do I compile the response so that any tags bind with the data?